Show that two summands of a direct sum are invariant under a linear operator
Given two linear operators $T,S\in L(V)$ such that $T$ and $S$ commute ($T\circ S=S\circ T$) and $T^2=T$. Show that:
(a) $V=ker(T)\bigoplus im(T)$.
(b) each summand is invariant under $S$.

So far I have proven (a): Started by taking $x\in V.$ Since $T$ is idempotent, then $T^2x=Tx$. Then, $T(x-Tx)=0$. This means that $x-Tx=\alpha$ for some $\alpha\in ker (T)$. Then, $x=Tx+\alpha$. Showing that $V= im(T)+ ker(T)$
Now, let's take $y\in im(T)\bigcap ker(T)$. Now, in particular, $y\in im(T),$ so $y=Tx_0$ for some $x_0\in V$.  By applying $T$ to both sides: $Ty=T^2x_0$. Since $y\in ker(T)$, then $Ty=T^2x_0=Tx_0=y=0$.
Meaning that $im(T)\bigcap ker(T)= \{ 0 \}$. We can conclude that $V=ker(T)\bigoplus im(T)$.
The question is: How can I prove (b) after this?

If $x\in\ker(T)$, will $S(x)$ be in $\ker(T)$? One way to find out is to figure out what happens when you evaluate $T$ at $S(x)$. If $y=T(v)$, is $S(y)$ in the image of $T$? Can you write $S(y)=T(\text{something....})$?

Evaluating $T$ at $S(x)$ gives me $S(T(x))=T(S(x))$ (given that  $S,T$  commute). Or I'm I wrong

And to you know what $T(S(x))=S(T(x))$ is, given where $x$ started in?

Well, since $x\in ker T$, then $T(x)=0$. So , $T(S(x))=S(T(x))=S(0). $ For any linear operator it holds that $L(0)=0$, so $S(0)=0$. In particular, we have that $T(S(x))=S(0)=0$, which implies that $S(x)\in ker T$. Is this correct?

So if $x\in\ker(T)$ then $S(x)\in\ker(T)$, so $\ker(T)$ is invariant under $S$.

Yes, I was forgetting a very important fact: The fact that any linear operator evaluated at the $0$ vector is $0. $ This is why in my first comment I couldn't conclude that $S(0)=0$.

@ArturoMagidin As for proving that $im (T) $ is invariant under $S$: If $y\in im (T)$, then $ y= Tx'$ for some $x'\in V$. Applying $S$ to both sides, $S(y)=S(T(x'))= T(S(x'))$. Is this enought to prove that  $im (T) $ is invariant under $S$?
